# Access dynamically created htmlgenericcontrols like div,label and checkbox using c#

Tags: c#, html, htmlgenericcontrol

I have created some div, label and checkbox using htmlgenericcontrol with runat="server". these dynamically created div is added inside the main div which is created at the design time.
Now, i want to access the checkbox which is there inside dynamically created div using c# on page load.
my dynamic div created using c# looks like this -

```
<div id='firstdiv'> 
<div id='seconddiv'>
              <label id='lbl' >
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="check" runat="server">                                                                          
                  <div id='thirddiv'></div>
              </label>
</div></div>
```

I tried below options but none of them worked -

> HtmlGenericControl chkfirstdiv =
>   HtmlGenericControl)maindiv.FindControl(strchkfirstdiv) as
>   HtmlGenericControl;
>
> HtmlGenericControl chkfirstdiv1 =
>   HtmlGenericControl)FindControl(strchkfirstdiv) as HtmlGenericControl;
>
> LiteralControl literalControl =
>   LiteralControl)maindiv.FindControl(strchkfirstdiv);

Can anyone help in accessing the dynamic checkbox inside dynamic div?

Answer (score 0):

For WebForms, you should create the control as `<asp:Checkbox Id="MyCheckbox" runat="server" Text="Check" />` and the designer should generate `Checkbox MyCheckbox` for you and it's `Checked` property will be populated on postback without the need to call FindControl(..).

Comment: I have create asp:checkbox instead of input tupe=checkbox, but still i am not able to access that chekbox on button click

Answer (score 0):

asp buttons will be accessed based on their names not IDs so place a name attribute inside checkbox definition like `<asp:Checkbox Id="MyCheckbox" name="myCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Check" />` and access myCheckBox in backend on click event